# CSS different columns settings

Tags: html, css

I have this div:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%; -moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-gap: 2%; -webkit-column-gap: 2%;">text...text</div>
```

I need to make the last column start below the other ones. I think a picture gonna help:

[image: 3 columns layout]

The cable image is wider than the columns, so it's out of this div. HTML `align=top` on the image won't work. Can I control a single column?

Any ideas? Any one...

Layout structure:

```
<div>
<div style="width: 100%; background-image: url(images/bg_pg10-11.jpg); background-repeat: repeat;">
    <div style="width: 100%;"><img src="images/port/pg10_11.png" alt="" width="89%" border="0" style="margin: 1%; margin-top: 2%; margin-bottom: 1%; margin-left: 5.5%;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%;"><img src="../images/port/tit_notas_merc2.png" alt="" width="20.5%" border="0" style="margin-bottom: 7%; margin-left: 5.5%;"></div>
    <div style="width: 73%; margin-left: 19%;"><img src="images/port/titulo_pg10-11_pt.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0"></div>
    <img src="images/img01_pg10-11.png" width="32%" border="0" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 68%;" ALIGN="Top">
    <div style="width: 73%; margin-left: 19%; margin-top: 2%;">
        <div class="txtInterno" style="position:relative; width: 100%; border:0px solid #000000; -moz-column-count:3; -webkit-column-count:3; -moz-column-gap:2%; -webkit-column-gap:2%;">
            <img src="../images/retangulo_tri_vd2.png" alt="" width="100%" border="0">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Durante muito tempo o gás natural era “persona non grata” na exploração de petróleo, pois exigia uma série de procedimentos de segurança que encareciam e complicavam as atividades de extração. Mas, a
            partir dos anos 1980, o consumo entrou em expansão e o gás natural transformou-se em uma das fontes de energia fóssil a registrar maior crescimento no mundo.
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more HTML and CSS code so we can see what you have going on with the entire document. PS - you should not use inline styles; rather you should use external style sheets for better code maintainability.

Comment: I use inline for developing. Gonna be external when finished.

Comment: Using inline for developing is just making your developing time longer and more tedious. Whenever you start up on something you should have have a css file handy. Should js fid this or put it on a site so we can see it in better detail

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put the image inside the div for the text to be able to "see" where it should start. You can use `overflow: visible;` on the div to allow the image to render outside the div.

Edit:
I have it working, but issues arise when the div is set to column-mode..
http://jsfiddle.net/D2zmV/1/

Edit2: 
Second version, using a background image to extend the parts that gets cut off. (Thanks to Alexander Lozada for the hint)
http://jsfiddle.net/cU82S/1/

Comment: or perhaps he could just set a positive `top` margin on the third column after setting it to `relative`?  Unless the page is responsive.

Comment: It's responsive @AlexanderLozada

Comment: @Thoronwen if I use overflow text won't leak?

Comment: The good news is: in my fiddle the text won't overflow. The bad news is: the image won't either (it gets cut off) as long as the div is in column-mode. D: http://jsfiddle.net/UrD2a/ (I'm testing in Chrome)

Comment: Could you do something like have the image not collide at all, and then have an `inline-block` with a set height in the targeted column to keep it down at a certain distance?

Comment: Seems like you can, but the image or inline block is difficult to position. It has to be at the right place in the text..